# how to configure squid to accept more users?

Tags: squid

I use squid as a private proxy server but when many users use it sometimes he gives the http 500 error

Comment: Can you please show the relevant part of your squid log file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably your squid configuration file (probably /etc/squid/squid.conf) include acl for connection limit, something like

```
acl maxuserconnections maxconn 3
```

You can try to locate this using

```
grep maxconn /etc/squid/* -R
```

If you adjust relevant maxconn acl, remember to restart squid (/etc/init.d/squid restart or similar, depending on your installation).

Comment: mazgalici: if this helped you, you should accept this answer by pressing accept answer button (http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1033/how-can-i-accept-answers-to-my-questions)